# set type unordered - error in python - pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I know I have to take this step, but I don't know how to do it:

By using the NASA Space Science Data Coordinated Archive, we gathered information about each module used in each mission. **As you did when you created the samples tables, create six new columns, three for the lunar modules and three for the command modules:**

- Module name
- Module mass
- Module mass diff

Fill in any NaN values with 0:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8184/2992438938.py in <module>
----> 1 missions['Lunar module (LM)'] = {'Eagle (LM-5)', 'Intrepid (LM-6)', 'Antares (LM-8)', 'Falcon (LM-10)', 'Orion (LM-11)', 'Challenger (LM-12)'}
      2 missions['LM mass (kg)'] = {15103, 15235, 15264, 16430, 16445, 16456}
      3 missions['LM mass diff'] = missions['LM mass (kg)'].diff()
      4 missions['LM mass diff'] = missions['LM mass diff'].fillna(value=0)
      5 

C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   3610         else:
   3611             # set column
-> 3612             self._set_item(key, value)
   3613 
   3614     def _setitem_slice(self, key: slice, value):

C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
   3782         ensure homogeneity.
   3783         """
-> 3784         value = self._sanitize_column(value)
   3785 
   3786         if (

C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _sanitize_column(self, value)
   4508         if is_list_like(value):
   4509             com.require_length_match(value, self.index)
-> 4510         return sanitize_array(value, self.index, copy=True, allow_2d=True)
   4511 
   4512     @property

C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\construction.py in sanitize_array(data, index, dtype, copy, raise_cast_failure, allow_2d)
    557         if isinstance(data, (set, frozenset)):
    558             # Raise only for unordered sets, e.g., not for dict_keys
--> 559             raise TypeError(f"'{type(data).__name__}' type is unordered")
    560 
    561         # materialize e.g. generators, convert e.g. tuples, abc.ValueView

TypeError: 'set' type is unordered
```

Code used:

```
missions['Lunar module (LM)'] = ['Eagle (LM-5)', 'Intrepid (LM-6)', 'Antares (LM-8)', 'Falcon (LM-10)', 'Orion (LM-11)', 'Challenger (LM-12)']
missions['LM mass (kg)'] = {15103, 15235, 15264, 16430, 16445, 16456}
missions['LM mass diff'] = missions['LM mass (kg)'].diff()
missions['LM mass diff'] = missions['LM mass diff'].fillna(value=0)

missions['Command module (CM)'] = ['Columbia (CSM-107)', 'Yankee Clipper (CM-108)', 'Kitty Hawk (CM-110)', 'Endeavor (CM-112)', 'Casper (CM-113)', 'America (CM-114)']
missions['CM mass (kg)'] = {5560, 5609, 5758, 5875, 5840, 5960}
missions['CM mass diff'] = missions['CM mass (kg)'].diff()
missions['CM mass diff'] = missions['CM mass diff'].fillna(value=0)

missions
```

Pedido do user:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_8184/3771249595.py in <module>
      1 missions['Lunar module (LM)'] = ['Eagle (LM-5)', 'Intrepid (LM-6)', 'Antares (LM-8)', 'Falcon (LM-10)', 'Orion (LM-11)', 'Challenger (LM-12)']
----> 2 missions['LM mass (kg)'] = {15103, 15235, 15264, 16430, 16445, 16456}
      3 missions['LM mass diff'] = missions['LM mass (kg)'].diff()
      4 missions['LM mass diff'] = missions['LM mass diff'].fillna(value=0)
      5 

C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __setitem__(self, key, value)
   3610         else:
   3611             # set column
-> 3612             self._set_item(key, value)
   3613 
   3614     def _setitem_slice(self, key: slice, value):

C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _set_item(self, key, value)
   3782         ensure homogeneity.
   3783         """
-> 3784         value = self._sanitize_column(value)
   3785 
   3786         if (

C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in _sanitize_column(self, value)
   4508         if is_list_like(value):
   4509             com.require_length_match(value, self.index)
-> 4510         return sanitize_array(value, self.index, copy=True, allow_2d=True)
   4511 
   4512     @property

C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\construction.py in sanitize_array(data, index, dtype, copy, raise_cast_failure, allow_2d)
    557         if isinstance(data, (set, frozenset)):
    558             # Raise only for unordered sets, e.g., not for dict_keys
--> 559             raise TypeError(f"'{type(data).__name__}' type is unordered")
    560 
    561         # materialize e.g. generators, convert e.g. tuples, abc.ValueView

TypeError: 'set' type is unordered
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `missions['Lunar module (LM)'] = ...` line to this:

```
missions['Lunar module (LM)'] = ['Eagle (LM-5)', 'Intrepid (LM-6)', 'Antares (LM-8)', 'Falcon (LM-10)', 'Orion (LM-11)', 'Challenger (LM-12)']
```

`{...}` creates a [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set), which is ordered (sorted), as the error message indicates. On the other hand, `[...]` creates a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list), which is not ordered, and which is what Pandas expects.

Comment: I tried it that way, but got the same error, only with "[]" in place of "{}"

Comment: Will you please add the full error that  comes when you use my code, to the question?

Comment: im edited because is too long, see in answer, last code

Comment: Oh, it's the same error, but for a differnent line. Change the `{` and `}` to `[` and `]` on the second line.

Comment: really grateful, this worked, im not had idea of difference in between "{}" and "[]"

Comment: Actually, it is the inverse. Sets are unordered, and lists are ordered. The links you provided for the docs confirms this: "A set object is an **unordered** collection of distinct hashable objects".